# Angular RxJS pipe tap

Tags: angular, rxjs

The following code is from https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6. The .tap throws the compilation error but the code works without it.

**hero.service.ts:**

```
 getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {

    return this.httpClient.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
              .pipe(
                tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')), //It works without this line
                catchError( this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []) )
              );
  }
```

**in-memory-data.service.ts:** This mocks the response on httpClient.get

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  constructor() { 
  }

  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following compile error:

```
Type 'Observable<{} | Hero[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero[]>'. 
Type '{} | Hero[]' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'. 
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'. 
Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'. [2322]
```

It does seem like the object returned is {Hero[]} while its expecting just an array Hero[].
I tried to fix it with,

```
createDb() {
  const heroes: Hero[] = [
    {id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice'},
    ...
  ]; 
  return heroes;
}
```

but createDb() return type is Observable{}. That begs the following questions:

1. If it's a mismatch, how did it work without the .tap line?
2. How to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the import statement in hero.service.ts as,

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

All it took was,

```
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The compilation error thrown is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In your in-memory-data.service.ts you are trying to return an array inside an object. This is the issue that you're getting the compile error.

Instead of `return {heroes}` just try `return heroes`.

Comment: I've already mentioned in the post that I've tried it and I get the same error.

Comment: I think what Bayramali wrote holds true; you haven't defined the return type on your `createDb()`, doing `createDb: Observable<Hero[]>` would give you other compilation errors because the types returned do not match the expected return type. Making this explicit makes for better type checking and readability of your code.

Comment: I agree the code could be better. I left it as shown in the official tutorial so it's easy to understand. The method signature is ''''abstract createDb(reqInfo?: RequestInfo): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}>;''''. I can't change that.